# GDB - No Debugging Symbols Found -

Tags: c++, linux, compilation, gdb

So I am hosting an OpenTibia-Server which is 8.6 . Sometimes the server freezes and I dont get to know what causes it to freeze so I asked my friend to help me and he told me to compile the console with gdb option. I did. But when  I attach the console to GDB after it freezes, it says no debugging symbol found. I've added the options `-g` and `-s` too (line 6) but it doesnt work.

here's my Makefile.am:

```
noinst_PROGRAMS = theforgottenserver

CXXFLAGS = -pipe -std=gnu++11
AM_CXXFLAGS = $(XML_CPPFLAGS) $(OTSERV_FLAGS) $(LUA_CFLAGS) $(DEBUG_FLAGS)\
$(MYSQL_FLAGS) $(SQLITE_FLAGS) $(PGSQL_FLAGS) $(PROFILER_FLAGS)\
$(OPTIONAL_FLAGS) -D_THREAD_SAFE -D_REENTRANT -Wall -Wextra -Wno-strict-aliasing -llua5.1 -I/usr/include/lua5.1 -g -s

theforgottenserver_LDADD = $(LUA_LIBS)

if USE_MYSQL
MAYBE_MYSQL = databasemysql.cpp databasemysql.h
endif
if USE_SQLITE
MAYBE_SQLITE = databasesqlite.cpp databasesqlite.h
endif
if USE_PGSQL
MAYBE_PGSQL = databasepgsql.cpp databasepgsql.h
endif
if LOGIN_SERVER
MAYBE_LOGIN = gameservers.cpp gameservers.h
endif
if OT_ADMIN
MAYBE_OTADMIN = admin.cpp admin.h
endif

theforgottenserver_SOURCES = account.h actions.cpp actions.h $(MAYBE_OTADMIN) \
        allocator.cpp allocator.h baseevents.cpp baseevents.h beds.cpp \
        beds.h chat.cpp chat.h combat.cpp combat.h condition.cpp condition.h \
        config.h configmanager.cpp configmanager.h connection.cpp connection.h \
        const.h container.cpp container.h creature.cpp creature.h \
        creatureevent.cpp creatureevent.h cylinder.cpp cylinder.h database.cpp \
        database.h databasemanager.cpp databasemanager.h $(MAYBE_MYSQL) \
        $(MAYBE_SQLITE) $(MAYBE_PGSQL) depot.cpp depot.h dispatcher.cpp \
        dispatcher.h exception.cpp exception.h fileloader.cpp fileloader.h \
        game.cpp game.h $(MAYBE_LOGIN) globalevent.cpp globalevent.h group.cpp \
        group.h house.cpp house.h housetile.cpp housetile.h ioban.cpp ioban.h \
        ioguild.cpp ioguild.h iologindata.cpp iologindata.h iomap.cpp iomap.h \
        iomapserialize.cpp iomapserialize.h item.cpp item.h itemattributes.cpp \
        itemattributes.h items.cpp items.h luascript.cpp luascript.h \
        mailbox.cpp mailbox.h manager.cpp manager.h map.cpp map.h monster.cpp \
        monster.h monsters.cpp monsters.h movement.cpp movement.h \
        networkmessage.cpp networkmessage.h npc.cpp npc.h otpch.h otserv.cpp \
        otsystem.h outfit.cpp outfit.h outputmessage.cpp outputmessage.h \
        party.cpp party.h player.cpp player.h position.cpp position.h \
        protocol.cpp protocol.h protocolgame.cpp protocolgame.h \
        protocolhttp.cpp protocolhttp.h protocollogin.cpp protocollogin.h \
        protocolold.cpp protocolold.h quests.cpp quests.h raids.cpp raids.h \
        rsa.cpp rsa.h scheduler.cpp scheduler.h scriptmanager.cpp \
        scriptmanager.h server.cpp server.h spawn.cpp spawn.h spells.cpp \
        spells.h status.cpp status.h talkaction.cpp talkaction.h teleport.cpp \
        teleport.h templates.h textlogger.cpp textlogger.h thing.cpp thing.h \
        tile.cpp tile.h tools.cpp tools.h town.h trashholder.cpp trashholder.h \
        waitlist.cpp waitlist.h waypoints.h weapons.cpp weapons.h vocation.cpp \
        vocation.h
```

and here is what I get on Terminal when I attach `GDB` and run `bt`
[image]

Comment: Your screen dump showed that you attached gdb to the "screen" process, and not your program. You attached it to the wrong process.

Comment: what should i do ?

Comment: Attach gdb to the right process.

Comment: Clean the build, and build again, looking at the output from the compilation commands and see if the flags you expect are being used.

Answer (score 0):

> I've added the options -g and -s

The `-g` option tells the compiler to emit debugging info.

The `-s` option tells the linker to *remove* (strip) debugging info. You *don't* want that option.

You also need to attach to correct process (not the `screen` that you have attached to). Once you attach correct process, you will need to issue `(gdb) thread apply all where` command, and the *complete* output from that command may allow someone familiar with the OpenTibia to diagnose the deadlock.

Note: you don't actually need a debugging version of OpenTibia Server: the output from `thread apply all where` is likely to point to the problem even without debugging info.